# Expand/Collapse Accordion by time. HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

is it possible to make auto collapse the accordion by time? i've tried using remove class in javascript, but nothing happen, please check the javascript, where the problem of my code, also please see comment at the html code. thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.acc-btn { 
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px 25px;
  background:#34495E;
  border-bottom:1px solid #2C3E50;
}

.acc-content {
  height:0px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#2C3E50;
}

.acc-content-inner {
  padding:30px;
}

.open1 {
  height: auto;
}

.open2 {
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font:700 20px/26px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function hideshow() {
    classList.remove('open1', 'open2');
    var h = parseInt(new Date().getHours());
    if (h >= 1 && h < 2) {
      classList.add('open1');
    }
    if (h >= 23 && h < 1) {
      classList.add('open2');
    }
    hideshow();
  }(document.querySelector('.acc-container'));
</script>

<div class="acc-container">
    <div class="acc-btn"><h1>Heading 1</h1></div> 
    <div class="acc-content open1"><!-- I want collapse this at 01:00 till 02:00 -->
      <div class="acc-content-inner">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="acc-btn"><h1>Heading 2</h1></div> 
    <div class="acc-content open2"><!-- I want collapse this at 23:00 till 01:00 -->
      <div class="acc-content-inner">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you already tried that is not working? We are not source code providers. We may help out, but not create code for others

Comment: @Psi im just started learn js, im so confuse, jst homework for im at highschool, i've tried, but nothing result. so im delete script before. search at google too much worth my time, so im came here :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() > 18 && d.getHours() < 19)
   $('.acc-btn').first().slideUp();
if(d.getHours() > 19 && d.getHours() < 20)
   $('.acc-btn').last().slideUp();
```